# Upstart setting uid from extracted parameter

Tags: upstart

I have a configuration file in my Ubuntu server. When I tried to migrate starting of some process to Upstart, I don't find solution to extract the uid and gid from my configuration file and pass them to setuid and setgid upstart's commands !

I tried to do this in script block, I extracted my uid/gid but I can't execute setuid or setgid from script block.

Can someone have any idea ?

Regards,
/requinham

Comment: Maybe http://serverfault.com/ suits your question better.

Comment: I think that is a general question about upstart not specially dedicated to server world.

Comment: But SO is a site for programming related questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible  to do this with actual version of Upstart. Maybe in the future version. But I can resolve this need on script part with start-stop-daemon command because this command have several interresant options like setting gid uid or sched priority.
Just use it in your upstart conf file.

Regards, 
/requinham